# getting latest test results

Tags: mysql

I have a database with 3 tables.

The first table contains students with fields fldID, fldName, fldPIN etc.

The second table contains a list of questions the student must answer with fields studentID and questionID

The third table contains one row for each time a student has answered a question and has fields studentID, questionID, response and score. There may be multiple answers per question.

I would like a query that allows me to get a students name (via their PIN) and a list of questions they need to answer and also their most recent score per question. The questions that are unanswered would have a score of null.

I'm unsure how to do the joind for this.

Many thanks for any help.

Dave

I have since come up with this sql. Could you take a look and let me know if this is valid or really bad!! I was struggling to understand your posts so struggled on to come up with this.

```
SELECT
`tbldelegate`.`fldFirstName`,
`tbldelegate`.`fldSurname`,
`tbldelegatequestions`.`fldQuestionID`,
`latestScores`.`fldScore`
FROM
`tbldelegate`
Left Join `tbldelegatequestions` ON `tbldelegatequestions`.`fldDelegateID` = `tbldelegate`.`fldID`
Left Join (SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT  max(fldID) as maxID
FROM tblscoredata 
GROUP BY 
`tblscoredata`.`fldDelegateID`,
`tblscoredata`.`fldSection`,
`tblscoredata`.`fldQuestion`
) AS x INNER JOIN `tblscoredata` AS f ON f.fldID = x.maxID) AS `latestScores` ON `latestScores`.`fldQuestion` = `tbldelegatequestions`.`fldQuestionID`
WHERE
`tbldelegate`.`fldPIN` =  '11'
```

Comment: How do you identify which response is tha last? Is there a timestamp in the third table?

Comment: Yes, there is a timestamp and an auto increment id column in the third table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the names of some of the tables, but something like this should do the trick.

```
SELECT s.fldName, sq.questionId, r.score 
FROM students s
INNER JOIN studentQuestions sq ON s.fldID = sq.studentID 
LEFT JOIN questionResponses r ON sq.questionID = r.questionID AND sq.studentID = r.studentId 
WHERE s.fldPIN = 12345;
```

Try this to get the latest, or unanswered result for each question the student has to answer (this is based on using auto_increment ids and newer records having a higher id value).

```
SELECT s.fldName, sq.questionID, r.score 
FROM students s
INNER JOIN studentQuestions sq ON s.id = sq.studentID
LEFT JOIN questionResponses r ON sq.questionId = r.questionID AND sq.studentID = r.studentId
LEFT OUTER JOIN questionResponses r2 ON sq.questionID = r2.questionID AND sq.studentID   = r2.studentID AND r.id < r2.id
WHERE r2.id IS NULL AND s.fldPIN = 12345
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but will this also list ALL responses to a question? I only want the latest response to a question. How would I amend this?

Comment: Are there any other fields in the responses table? We need either a unique ID for each post, or a timestamp so that we can display the latest response.

Comment: I have added a speculative solution for if you have an ID field available.

Comment: Thanks for this Gordon. There is both a date field and an auto increment id field. I was trying to do things with a max functionality on the date field but was coming rather unstuck!

Comment: @Dave: I added an answer (since there is no formatting in comments) using MAX.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I was struggling to understand what was happening in your queries so carried on along the lines I was trying. Could you take a look at my sql and let me know if it is valid or really bad!!

Comment: I've tried testing your query and it doesn't yield the correct results. Klas' or my solution, in my opinion, the best approach to the problem and will produce the best results. 
It used to be bad practice to use sub-queries in MySQL as it would greatly reduce the speed of a query, however if you are using MySQL version > 5.1.28 then this problem has been dealt with by the optimisation team. All sub-queries are pre-processed and converted into a query using joins.

Comment: So effectively if your method was written to produce the results you would expect the optimisation engine would generate intermediate query which would likely read something similar to my query!

I would argue that it is still best to use JOINS over sub-queries as you avoid the pre-processing time and the queries can be read more clearly.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I have tried your query and it is working but I just don't understand the joins and the 'on' statements. I rarely do sql work so I find it quite difficult to pick it up each time I need to. Could yo upossibly explain the stages of the query and what each part is doing? I understand if this is asking for too much!!

Comment: The best way to get an understanding of joins would be to go to [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). This explains what a join is and the different variations. It only takes 10 minutes to read thorough and is very concise. Could you accept my answer please? I feel I've been quite helpful!

Comment: I have accepted your answer, thanks for your help on this. I am off to read the tutorial now.

Answer (score 0):

Gordons answer is excellent. However, since Dave was struggling with MAX I can't resist posting a variant using it. 
My guess is that Gordons answer has better performance and that his answer would probably be my choice of the two.

```
SELECT s.fldName, sq.questionID, r.score 
FROM students s
INNER JOIN studentQuestions sq ON s.fldID = sq.studentID 
LEFT JOIN questionResponses r ON sq.questionId = r.questionID AND sq.studentID = r.studentId
WHERE r.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM questionResponses r2 where r2.id = r.id)
AND s.fldPIN = 12345
```